# how to take video and audio from a stream and output to a video file as well as images

Tags: c, windows, opencv, video-streaming, directshow

I am currently trying to make a program that will take a stream coming in, like a webcam and a microphone, and I am trying to save both the video and audio into an AVI file and be able to save out the information out to images. I've tried to do this with DirectShow and OpenCV, but I've had some trouble since I have audio that I would like to include in the AVI file, but cannot see a way to use OpenCV to save Audio information.

I've also looked into FFMPEG, but I don't see much online about working with streams coming in from Windows.

Any information or documentation would be great.

I am trying to develop this on a Windows compatible machine.

Thanks

Comment: OpenCV does not deal with Audio streams. This page has tutorials that can show you how to achieve what you want using ffmpeg: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html

Comment: Karl you always seem to come to my rescue with exactly the right information that I need.

Comment: Hehe. I'm not stalking you, relax.

Answer (score 0):

We have a cross platform vision system framework that may solve your needs:
http://www.simplecv.org

Here is how you do it in our code:

```
from SimpleCV import *
import time

cam = Camera()
visstream = VideoStream("foo.avi")

while(True):
    image = cam.getImage()
    image.save("c:/blah.png")
    image.save(visstream)
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: I have a similar setup with DirectShow and OpenCV. However because of the lack of audio and because I would have to add in another API to handle an audio stream I wouldn't get the desired effect that I am looking for.